# How to make tableview navigation at top

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I want to make `navigation` at the top of a `tableView` like in attached image. Also how do I add the `title` at the top?

Below is the image:

[image]

Comment: means you want navigation bar at top of the table view?

Comment: History:- `UIView + UILabel`, Month :- `headerView of tableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a ViewController, not a TableViewController.
2. ViewController -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller
3. You can set the title in Interface Builder or in Code
4. Create a Horizontal StackView at the top of your view set top, leading, trailing constraints to 0, and a height.
5. Inside your StackView add a UIButton "<", UILabel, UIButton ">", and connect actions and outlets in your ViewController code
6. Set the StackView Distribution to Fill Equally
7. Add a TableView and TableViewCell below your StackView and set constraints to fill the view.

[image]

[image]

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
    self.navigationController?.title = "History"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 74.0/255.0, green: 124.0/255.0, blue: 199.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

[image]

In relation to your further question below.  Yes you can still do this if you are coming from a TabBar Controller:

[image]

Comment: I'm using a Tab bar controller, will I still have to use the "Embed In > Navigation Controller"? Or it that a  "bad" idea?

Comment: Yes, you can still embed it in a Navigation Controller, from a TabBar Controller.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was after. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In xcode choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller, then you can see the title on the top of your tableview, then search "nav item" and drag it to top of tableview navigation, and put the title text from setting. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Select your **View Controller** in **Storyboard**

In the Top Menu go to **Editor**-->**Embed In**-->**Navigation Controller**[image]

Then **Automatically** **Navigation Bar** Appers on the top of Your **View Controller**

To Add Title **Select** **Navigation Bar** in **View Controller** then in Attributes Inspector you can give the Title[image]